# Can I shift specific values in one data column to another column while keeping the other values unchanged?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example dataset that I have:

```
C1      C2
 1       1
NaN      1
 2       0
NaN      0
NaN      1
 1       1
 2       2
 2       2
NaN      1
```

I want to take all the values that have "1" in them in the Column "C2" and shift them to replace the adjacent values in column "C1".

So the output should look like:

```
C1      C2
 1       1
 1       1
 2       0
 NaN     0
 1       1
 1       1
 2       2
 2       2
 1       1
```

Alternatively, I could create a new column with these values replaced. Main point is, that I need all the "1s" in C2 TO replace the NaN values in C1.

I can't do find all NaN and replace with 1, because there are some NaN values that should stay in C1.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `df['C1'] = df['C1'].fillna(df.loc[df.C2.eq(1), 'C1'].ffill())`?

Comment: The problem is this replaces the whole row of values, and I only need the values with "1" to replace the adjacent values in c1. 

The problem is that I have some correct data in C1 and other correct data in C2, but if I can shift all the data with the value "1" (in C2) to C1, then the data in C1 would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DF.mask()` api to apply values from one column to another in rows where some condition is true (e.g. ==1).

```
value = 1
source_col = 1
target_col = 0

condition = df[source_col] == value

df[target_col] = df[target_col].mask(condition,
                                     df[source_col])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with  `fillna` on `C1` along with `series.where`which would help retain only 1s from `C2`

```
df['C1'] = df['C1'].fillna(df['C2'].where(df['C2'].eq(1)))
```

---

```
    C1  C2
0  1.0   1
1  1.0   1
2  2.0   0
3  NaN   0
4  1.0   1
5  1.0   1
6  2.0   2
7  2.0   2
8  1.0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bfill/ffill` with `limit=1`:

```
df['C1'] = df['C1'].fillna(df.loc[df.C2.eq(1), 'C1']
                             .ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1)
                          )
```

Output:

```
    C1  C2
0  1.0   1
1  1.0   1
2  2.0   0
3  NaN   0
4  1.0   1
5  1.0   1
6  2.0   2
7  2.0   2
8  1.0   1
```